# Node.js fs.writeFile returning unexpected token syntax error

Tags: node.js, fs

The following node.js test code fragment works perfectly when run for the first time (creating the file), but fails to overwrite the file once it's already created and instead generates a syntax error when the code is run a second time: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token'. The Node docs say that fs.writeFile "Asynchronously writes data to a file, replacing the file if it already exists. data can be a string or a buffer." Not sure what I'm doing wrong or missing regarding this, thanks! I'm on Node 4.2.2

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', 'utf8', function (err) {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    else{
        console.log('It\'s saved!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly on my system. I'm on Node v4.2.1. But i guess that's not the problem.

Comment: You should show the full stack trace that's displayed when the error occurs.

Comment: imac:najii jg$ node app.js
undefined:1
Howdy Node.js
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token H
    at Object.parse (native)
    at loadDatabase (/Users/jg/Desktop/najii/najii-v002.js:26:16)
    at Object.startServer [as start] (/Users/jg/Desktop/najii/najii-v002.js:128:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jg/Desktop/najii/app.js:3:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)

Comment: The above is the full error, but not sure why it won't format here when I pasted it in…sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the stack trace you've supplied in your comment, the error you're seeing is a problem with another part of your code, not the snippet you've posted.

Furthermore, it appears that you (or some other function is doing so behind the scenes) are attempting to `JSON.parse()` some string, but the string is not actually (valid) JSON (perhaps it is HTML or some other type). If you are getting this data from an HTTP response, you may want to check the value of `res.headers['content-type']` first because attempting to use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Thank you, mscdex, you were exactly right. The code above that had 'Hello Node.js' as one of the parameters was being read in at the beginning of the program and parsed incorrectly by JSON.parse…when I changed the line to '{"message" : "Hello Node.js"}' it worked as expected. Appreciate your extra set of eyes on this, thanks!